# Node Wrangler -- 'ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled' AttributeError

Tags: python, add-on, error

I ran into a problem while using Node Wrangler.When I try to use the 'Add Principled Setup' option in the Node Wrangler menu and select the desired texture/PBR material files blender gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\node_wrangler.py", line 2689, in execute
    if not active_node.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bl_idname'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try selecting the Principled BSDF node before trying to import your materials, that fixed it for me

Comment: If that's still in 2.82a, please file a bug report (Help > Report a Bug).